# Is there any simple and practical Single Sign-On and Single Sign-Off solutions using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Could anybody tell me some simple and practical Single Sign-On and Single Sign-Off solutions using asp.net ?

I have googled a lot, but most articles just can not work for Single Sign-On and Single Sign-Off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using OpenID with you ASP .NET app. A quick Google search yielded [this article](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/899303.aspx). (In fact StackOverflow's very authentication in based on OpenID).
Be aware though that the DotNetOpenAuth library does not work in medium trust, such that you won't be able to deploy the website to a shared host like Godaddy.